# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, anaconda, pymssql

I know that such error might appear if I named the file same as importing lib, but there are must be is something different, because the error persist even if try run that code below through the console:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251
import _mssql

connSQLserver = _mssql.connect(
                        server="localhost",
                        port=1433,
                        user="admin",
                        password="****",
                        database="master")
```

This is output:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8ecbd448023e> in <module>()
      2 import _mssql
      3 
----> 4 connSQLserver = _mssql.connect(
      5                         server="localhost",
      6                         port=1433,

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

I'm trying to connect to locally installed sql server 2014, using pymssql-2.1.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.

I tried even import `pymssql` , nothing changed. According to [official documentation](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/_mssql_examples.html), both library might be used. I use python 2.7.1 installed as a part of Anaconda, windows 7. Connection string might be wrong.

What may cause the error?

**upd**:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251
import _mssql 
print _mssql
```

*returns*

```
<module '_mssql' (built-in)>
```

`print _mssql.__file__`   returns `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: Could you run the code and please provide the whole error message.

Comment: What's the output you get when you run `import _mssql; print _mssql`?

Comment: OK, that's interesting, I haven't come across that module being built-in before.  I get `<module '_mssql' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\_mssql.pyd'>`, and your code works for me.  Which version of Python are you using?  Are you using a distribution such as Anaconda or Enthought Canopy?

Comment: I got that you mean, he tries to use _mssql or pymssql from Anaconda, not from library I just installed. Am I right, @LukeWoodward?

Comment: I have to admit I'm not familiar with Anaconda, so I don't know whether it does include `_mssql`.  The [documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) suggests not.  However, it does look to me that you are right: somewhere in Anaconda there is a copy of the `_mssql` module and Python is picking that up instead of the one in the pymssql library.

Comment: did u ever sort this out? im having the exact same issue rn

Comment: @Anthony I finally used another library, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249304/pyodbc-cant-connect-to-database

Comment: apparently the issue is that `.connect()` is not capitalized like so `.Connect()` i have yet to test this myself tho so who knows

Comment: Wow, @Anthony write it as answer and I will close the quest, thank you)

Comment: i just tested it and it actually worked!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply that `.connect(...)` must be capitalized like so `.Connect(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a python module as root, sometimes, the access rights to the modules files are limited for others than root.

Juste give recurse right as root to everyone:
by example for python 2.7 module, installed through pip2.7

> chmod -R a+rx /usr/local/lib/python2.7

You can check this is a permission problem by launching program through strace...

Comment: 20.04 installing pymssql had 660 for permissions for the shared libs, This post was our resolution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what gave you the idea to import `_pymssql`; the leading underscore should have given you the clue that this is a private utility module. Just import `pymssql`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try `_mssql.MSSQLConnection`

[from](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/_mssql.html)

Comment: As written in the docs, that class will be created after establishing the connection, in other words `connect()` must be called.

Comment: @ Rocketq I tried In [2]: _mssql.connect
Out[2]: <function _mssql.connect> Maybe  there is some problem with your MS SQL database ?

Comment: `_mssql.connect`  return the same error. How is sql server might be the problem, if this is just python cant find the function?