# pyodbc can't connect to database

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, connection-string, pyodbc

I'm using `pyodbc` library from [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows) and I'm connecting this way:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true; database = online_banking; autocommit = True')
```

I use `MSSQLLocalDB`because it's the default instance name for SQL Server 2014. And this last version of Python 2.7.

However I cant run any simple query, every if them raise the error, saying that there is no such object or in that particular case database:

```
cursor.execute('use online_banking;')
```

The full error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('08004', "[08004] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Database 'online_banking' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. (911) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

So what is wrong here?

There is only 1 instance installed and such `databases(.mdf)`
[image]
[image]

As you can see only 1 engine:

[image]

Selecting that engine will allow me to see `online_banking` db
[image]

**upd1** Database've been created this way:

```
CREATE DATABASE [online_banking]
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'online_banking', FILENAME = N'C:\...\online_banking.mdf' , 
  SIZE = 512000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 30%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'online_banking_log', FILENAME = N'C:\...\online_banking_log.ldf' , 
  SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 20GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

**upd2** I've used built-in tool `sqlcmd`. 
So this `sqlcmd  -S (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB -i C:\Users\1.sql -E` have shown, that 
`MSSQLLocalDB` doesn't have my database.

However `sqlcmd  -S localhost -i C:\Users\1.sql -E` performed successfully.
I'm totally confused, I' ve installed only one server, moreover SQL Management studio sees only one local server with my `online_banking` DB. This is look really weird to me.

Trying to use this connection string in Python

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost;Integrated Security=true; database = online_banking; autocommit = True')
```

causes the error below:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]\x... "". (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [01S00] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]\xcd\xe5\xe....xe8\xff (0); [28000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]\xce...ff "". (18456); [01S00] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]\xcd\xe.... (0)'
```

**upd3:** Specified mdf should be attached, got it:
Tried several ways, always errors (with database specified or not in connection string):

```
conn = pyodbc.connect( 

       r'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; database =online_banking; AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLSERVERINSAF\MSSQL\DATA\online_banking.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes; Integrated Security=true; database = online_banking;')

error: A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

I found out, that may be related with parent server which already have attached this db, but failed to solve this.

**upd4**
I tried simple code from [here](http://pastebin.com/nJr4Pdge)  to see if "online_banking" shows up in the list of databases for that instance. But faced another error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]\ - unreadable error

In addition that database [image] according to SSMS seems have already attached by `online_banking`  DB

Comment: Have you tried it with `Server=localhost` or `Server = localdb` only (add brackets if needed)?

Comment: Have you actually created an [online_banking] database in the `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` instance? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: @GordThompson I'm not sure about this, show DB given above. Is there possible to be more than 1 instances?

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB can have any number of named instances. Try the test code [here](http://pastebin.com/pZGxXiDH) and see if "online_banking" shows up in the list of databases.

Comment: If the "online_banking.mdf" file does indeed exist then you could try `r'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\whatever\online_banking.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes'`

Comment: @GordThompson The error changed, but I still have it ((

Comment: From the path to the .mdf file it looks like the `online_banking` database was created in a "regular" (not "LocalDB") SQL Server instance named `SQLSERVERINSAF`. Try the sample code [here](http://pastebin.com/nJr4Pdge) to see if "online_banking" shows up in the list of databases for *that* instance. If not, then open `(local)\SQLSERVERINSAF` in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and [Attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms190209%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) it.

Comment: So the [test code](http://pastebin.com/nJr4Pdge) to inspect the `(local)\SQLSERVERINSAF` instance did *not* list "online_banking" as one of the databases? (Also, remember that `(local)\INSTANCENAME` and `(LocalDB)\INSTANCENAME` are not the same thing.)

Comment: @GordThompson ops, It returned unreadable error as shown above

Comment: Can you connect to the `(local)\SQLSERVERINSAF` instance from SSMS?

Comment: if this is a default instance then it will be just server= <thenameofmachine>  
or localhost

Comment: Can you go sql server config and tell me how many servers are running and the names

Comment: @RhianA only one and his name SQLSERVERINSAF , but I may be wrong

Comment: @GordThompson How can I do that? I dont know how

Comment: Can send us a screenshot. Perhaps you have not connected through ssms

Comment: Do you have the native client installed?

Comment: Screenshot from sql configuration manager > sql services

Comment: Have you access this site? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195566

Comment: Wew no one provides you with that link. How odd. Goodluck.

Comment: What was the change?

Comment: Start the SQL Server Browser service. Launch SQL Server Management Studio. In the "Connect to Server" dialog, click the "Server name" drop-down and choose "<Browse for more...>" ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w3x99.png)). On the "Local Servers" tab of the "Browse for Servers" dialog, click the "+" beside "Database Engine". That should show you a list of local server instances. Mine looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl4kT.png). Please [edit] your question to show yours.

Comment: check this
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/36df4673-c3ec-4e30-bbdf-69a8690fd28b/odbc-error-sqlstate-28000-server-error-18452?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: @GordThompson updated

Comment: @RhianA 2800 error -  I allowed both auth. types. 08001 error - this`s local instance, he doesnt connect through TCP/IP I believe.

Comment: Excellent. Now if you select that instance in the "Browse for Servers" dialog and open it in SSMS can you see the "online_banking" database in the "Databases" list?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, I can see it. Look attached photo

Comment: Great! Now try the test code [here](http://pastebin.com/v18zDVXA) and see if you can connect.

Comment: @GordThompson This is magic)) Works as should. I just inserted values, thank you a lot. And don't forget to post smth as a answer to get 50 points))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turns out, the database in question was already attached to the default instance of SQL Server on the local machine, so all that was needed to connect was

```python
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
    r"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
    r"Server=(local);"
    r"Database=online_banking;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

There were two main points of confusion:

### Q: What is the name of a SQL Server "default instance"?

A: It doesn't have one.

When referring to a SQL Server instance by name, a *default instance* simply goes by the name of the machine, while a *named instance* is identified by `MachineName\InstanceName`. So, on a server named `PANORAMA`

- If we install a "default instance" of SQL Server we refer to it as `PANORAMA`.
- If we install a "named instance" called "SQLEXPRESS" we refer to it as `PANORAMA\SQLEXPRESS`.

If we are referring to a SQL server instance on the local machine we can use `(local)` instead of `PANORAMA`.

### Q: Do (local) and (localdb) mean the same thing?

A: NO.

`(local)` and `(local)\InstanceName` refer to "real" server-based instances of SQL Server. These are the instances that have been around since SQL Server was first released. They run as a service and are able to accept network connections and do all of the the things we expect a database server to do.

`(localdb)` and `(localdb)\InstanceName` references – with `(localdb)` usually capitalized as `(LocalDB)` for clarity – are used to connect to "SQL Server LocalDB" instances. These are temporary local SQL Server instances primarily intended for developers. For details see the following MSDN blog post:

[SQL Express v LocalDB v SQL Compact Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx)

Comment: Ideally you should pud the machine name rather local if deployed for multi user.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be a security issue.  You are using integrated security so it will use the security credentials of the windows login that the client program is running.  If that user or a group that the user belongs to does not have at least public access to the database, it will appear as if the database does not exist.  Either ensure that the user or a group that the user is a member of is [set up with a login](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215680%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and that it has at least [public access to your database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905164%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), or use SQL server authentication and send a username and password in your connection string.

Comment: I don't think that problem related with access problem. My PC has only one account and its me, and I'm the admin. Or am I should run PyCharm as admin?