# database not showing up in pyodbc but exists in Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

when I run this script either of these two statements:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.databases
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

in Sql Server Management Studio I get

> name
>
> ---
>
> master
>
> tempdb
>
> model
>
> msdb
>
> foofoo
>
> unitoo
>
> (6 rows affected)

where tempdb, foofoo, and unitoo are databases I have created.
Now looking in Object Explorer in Managment Studio, tempdb is under System Databases while the other two are under Databases/
the foofoo database was created by this ddl:

```
use master  
go
create database "foofoo"
go
use master
go
```

now when I run this python code:

```
    import pyodbc
    def PrintOutListOfLocalDatabases():
        connStr = (
        r"DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
        r"SERVER=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;"
        r"Integrated Security=true;")
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr, autocommit=True)
        crsr = cnxn.execute("SELECT name FROM sys.databases")
        for row in crsr.fetchall():
            print(row[0])
 
        crsr.close()
        cnxn.close()
```

I get

> master
>
> tempdb
>
> model
>
> msdb

The two databases under databases are not showing. If I browse to the sql server Data directory in File Explorer I see the .mdf and .ldf files for all 6 databases in the same place.

Why are two of the three databases I created are not returning when running the python code?

Comment: do you also use integrated security when you connect in management studio?

Comment: yes. I believe so.

Comment: you only need `SERVER=servername or ip\MSSQLLocalDB` i believe, if local then `localhost` should work

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, can you please comment with a full query string that works

Comment: @MitchWheat this is my local dev machine. It is the only machine. And I am the only user. so why would integrate security not work if I am the only login on the machine and am the only user on this machine and the only person who has created the databases under the same user identity using windows authentication?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249304/pyodbc-cant-connect-to-database

Comment: @maSTAShuFu changing the connection string server part to r"SERVER=MyMachineName;" resulted in Login failed exception.

and changing it to r"SERVER=localhost\MSSQLLocalDB;" results in a Login timeout

Comment: @MitchWheat. That worked! Thanks!